# How to remove a specific filter from the Filter.Filters slice in the gift library?

Tags: go, image-processing

I'm currently working on a small image editing application with fyne (ui) and gift (backend for image processing).

I want to apply the image edits whenever the user changes the value of the slider.

My problem is, that if I always add, e.g. a brightness filter, I get a lot of them, because the user might be dragging the slider many times. So I would always like to remove the last brightness filter from the Filter.Filters slice instead of always removing all filters with `Filters.Empty()` and reapplying all other filters, because that makes the realtime editing really slow. So instead of `Filters.Empty()` (removing all filters) I want to do something like `Filters.Remove(myFilter)` (removing only 1 specific Filter) (this is not a real function).

Is that possible?

gift: https://github.com/disintegration/gift

Comment: this post lacks clarity and details. IE: what are talking about ? Please consider to edit your post, adding reproducible code sample, references to the library etc, so we can understand your problem.

Comment: I added some more information

Comment: Isn't it possible to merely have two sets of filters: one "final" and another one ­— "preview", which will be applied in the UI, while the former will be applied to produce the final version of the image?

Comment: this seems possible. See here, the Filter property is publicly exposed https://github.com/disintegration/gift/blob/master/gift.go#L46 and reading (very quickly) the code consuming those filters, it does not appear harmful to manipulate this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code seems to work

```
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/png"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/disintegration/gift"
)

func main() {

    resize := gift.Resize(800, 0, gift.LanczosResampling)
    g := gift.New(
        resize,
        gift.UnsharpMask(1, 1, 0),
    )

    // say the resize filter is modified
    nresize := gift.Resize(400, 0, gift.LanczosResampling)
    // replace the filter
    for i, f := range g.Filters {
        if f == resize {
            g.Filters[i] = nresize
        }
    }

    src := loadImage("src.png")
    dst := image.NewRGBA(g.Bounds(src.Bounds()))
    g.Draw(dst, src)
    saveImage("dst.png", dst)

}
func loadImage(filename string) image.Image {
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("os.Open failed: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    img, _, err := image.Decode(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("image.Decode failed: %v", err)
    }
    return img
}

func saveImage(filename string, img image.Image) {
    f, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("os.Create failed: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    err = png.Encode(f, img)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("png.Encode failed: %v", err)
    }
}
```

then you have to figure out an api that suits you. maybe something like this

```golang
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/png"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/disintegration/gift"
)

type gifted struct {
    *gift.GIFT
}

func (g *gifted) Remove(filter gift.Filter) bool {
    for i, f := range g.Filters {
        if f == filter {
            copy(g.Filters[i:], g.Filters[i+1:])     // Shift a[i+1:] left one index.
            g.Filters[len(g.Filters)-1] = nil        // Erase last element (write zero value).
            g.Filters = g.Filters[:len(g.Filters)-1] // Truncate slice.
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func (g *gifted) Replace(old, new gift.Filter) bool {
    for i, f := range g.Filters {
        if f == old {
            g.Filters[i] = new
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func New(filters ...gift.Filter) *gifted {
    return &gifted{
        gift.New(filters...),
    }
}

func main() {

    resize := gift.Resize(800, 0, gift.LanczosResampling)
    g := New(
        resize,
        gift.UnsharpMask(1, 1, 0),
    )

    // say the resize filter is modified
    nresize := gift.Resize(400, 0, gift.LanczosResampling)
    // replace the filter
    g.Replace(resize, nresize)

    src := loadImage("src.png")
    dst := image.NewRGBA(g.Bounds(src.Bounds()))
    g.Draw(dst, src)
    saveImage("dst.png", dst)

}
func loadImage(filename string) image.Image {
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("os.Open failed: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    img, _, err := image.Decode(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("image.Decode failed: %v", err)
    }
    return img
}

func saveImage(filename string, img image.Image) {
    f, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("os.Create failed: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    err = png.Encode(f, img)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("png.Encode failed: %v", err)
    }
}
```